# Angular 7- Select and unselect disappear after clicking on it and came back after refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Made a filter feature but **when I click on it** it works:

[image: when_select]

but again when I  **unselect it, it disappears**

[image: unselect]

and only re-appears when I referesh the page also after selecting the filter it disable unselect don't know how can I fix any idea? please!

Here is my **node code**:

```
if (req.body.showcasefilter === "1") {
  query.showcase = '1';
}
   {
        $set:
            { 'showcase': '0' }
    },
```

Here is my **.Ts file**

```
if ($("#showcase_check:checked").val() === '1') {
  this.articlepara.showcasefilter = '1';
}
setShowcase(articleid, event) {
event.currentTarget.style.display = "none";

this.article.showcase(articleid, this.articlepara)
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      //console.log(res);
      this.showcasearticle.push(res.articleid);
      console.log(this.showcasearticle);

    },
```

Here is my **.HTML Code**

```
  <div class="flexcell">
  <a *ngIf="data.showcase==1 || helper.checkArticleArray(showcasearticle,data.articleid)"
    href="javascript:void(0);"
    (click)="setShowcase(data.articleid,$event)">
```

Comment: During refresh every variable in the component get refreshed since the constructor and ngOnInit methods are called. If you want to save the state of a control during refresh you need to create a service and store the value there. On ngOnInit check if the value is there. If it is there set the value or else initialize

Comment: why have you used `ngIf` ? it will show or hide the element based on the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to disable the element, try the following code:

```html
  <a [disabled]="data.showcase==1 || helper.checkArticleArray(showcasearticle,data.articleid)"
    href="javascript:void(0);"
    (click)="setShowcase(data.articleid,$event)">
```